# MySQL joint and count from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables: `users`,`members`, `visitors`, and `teams`

```
users table
user_id | name
---------------------
1       | John
2       | Jimmy
3       | Jack

members table
user_id | fingerprint_id
---------------------
1       | 20
2       | 21
3       | 22

visitors table
id  | fingerprint_id
---------------
1   | 20
2   | 20
3   | 22
4   | 21
5   | 21
6   | 22

teams table
id  | user_id 
---------------
1   | 1
2   | 1
3   | 2
4   | 3
5   | 2
6   | 1
```

how can I count the number of users from another table? like the result below

```
count
user_id | total in visitors| total in teams
-------------------------------
John    | 2                | 3
Jimmy   | 2                | 2
Jack    | 2                | 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried writing any SQL yet, and, if so, can you include that in your question?

Comment: I haven't tried to write anything in SQL, because actually, this is a small overview of my project in laravel. So from this question, I can find the logic that I apply in my project.

Answer (score 1):

A standard way of handling this is to perform the aggregations on the visitors and teams tables in two separate subqueries.  Then join to these subqueries to bring in the aggregates:

```sql
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    COALESCE(v.total_visitor, 0) AS `total in visitors`,
    COALESCE(t.total_team, 0) AS `total in teams`
FROM users u
INNER JOIN members m
    ON m.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT fingerprint_id, COUNT(*) AS total_visitor
    FROM visitors
    GROUP BY fingerprint_id
) v
    ON v.fingerprint_id = m.fingerprint_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS total_team
    FROM teams
    GROUP BY user_id
) t
    ON t.user_id = m.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT teams.user_id,count_visitors,count(1) FROM (
SELECT members.user_id,visitors_count.count_visitors  FROM
(SELECT fingerprint_id , count(1) as count_visitors
FROM visitors 
GROUP BY fingerprint_id) as visitors_count) 
JOIN members ON visitors_count.fingerprint_id = members.fingerprint_id) as members_visitors
JOIN teams on teams.user_id = members_visitors.user_id GROUP BY team.user_id
```